# What is the regular expression for matching white space among words in a sentence for FLEX?

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I want to first match the white spaces among words then want to count total number of white spaces in a sentence. I am trying in this below way ,

```
%{
#undef yywrap
#define yywrap() 1
int VowelCount = 0;
int ConsonantCount=0;
int CountWhiteSpace=0;
int CountNewLine=0;
int CountInteger=0;
int CountFloat=0;
%}
%%
[aeiouAEIOU] {++VowelCount;}
[bcdBCDfghFGHjklmnJKLMNpqrstPQRSTvwxyzVWXYZ] {++ConsonantCount;}
[0-9] {++CountInteger;}
[0-9]*[.][0-9]+ {++CountFloat;}
[\s]  {++CountWhiteSpace;}
\n    {++CountNewLine;}
end {return 0;}       
%%
int main(){
yylex();
printf("\nNumber of vowel in the given input  %d\n", VowelCount);
printf("\nNumber of consonant in the given input %d\n",ConsonantCount);
printf("\nNumber of integer in the given input %d\n",CountInteger);
printf("\nNumber of float in the given input %d\n",CountFloat);
printf("\nNumber of line in the given input %d\n",CountNewLine);
printf("\nTotal white space count %d\n",CountWhiteSpace); 
return 0;
}
```

but I am getting error something like:

**line 16:Warning, rule cannot be matched.**
I am able to achieve vowel, consonant, new line, integer and float count but I am facing for white space count. I want to count whitespace in below way:
input: I am Ashiqur Rahman.
Output:3 //number of white space among words I, am, Ashiqur, Rahman.
How can I achieve it in FLEX? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to match a space character, you can use `" "` or `[ ]` (or even `\` , but that can be hard to read). But that is not the equivalent of `\s` in typical regex libraries, which will match any single-byte whitespace character, including tabs and newlines. Flex does not recognise escape sequences like `\s`, `\d`, or`\w`, which might work in regex packages.

Flex does have two built-in sets which you can use inside a character class. (Note that "inside a character class" implies that you need to surround these with additional `[…]`):

- `[:space:]` means exactly what `\s` would mean: any whitespace character, horizontal or vertical.
- `[:blank:]` is only horizontal white space: spaces and tabs.

You can combine these freely with other characters in a character class. Thus, `[[:blank:]]` will match a single space or tab character, while `[[:space:],;]` will match any whitespace character at all as well as comma and semicolon.

Often, you would want to match a *sequence* of whitespace characters, not just a single one. Otherwise, you will miscount words; `the  other  one` has four spaces, but there are only three words.

To match a sequence, use the "one or more repetitions" operator, `+`: `[[:space:]]+`. This is also more efficient. And it doesn't stop you from counting characters as well, because in the action the variable `yyleng` is the number of characters matched by the pattern.

For more information, see the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).

Answer (score -1):

I asked the question when I was facing problem. Now I have solved my problem and I am posting here the answer so that who need the answer of this question can be benefited.

**Regular expression for matching white spaces in FLEX is :**

```
([ ])
```

**Note:** Must have contain a white space between two square brackets.